# css to set parent div width / height as images in slider

Tags: css, html, slider, size, css-position

I am trying to remove/override the hard-coded size of the following div on this http://demov3.joostrap.com

```
<div class="sequence" style="max-width: 1170px; height: 480px;">
```

I want the above div to be resized, dependant on the slide image size contained in the below div - so that I can get rid of the above width/height.

Slide image div below:

```
<div class="slide-image right" style="background-image: url(http://demov3.joostrap.com/images/1.jpg); background-position: 50% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;"></div>
```

Any ideas how I can do this with CSS only?

Comment: If you have inline styles in an element, they will take the highest priority. Try maybe with the !important flag... `height: auto !important;`

Comment: on the div class="sequence" (in chrome inspector) i can turn off the width and make height: auto !important; - but the whole div disappears. I am assuming it's because the slide div is a background-image :(

Comment: Please post a bit more relevent code, like some CSS and the HTML parts that make those two lines related somehow.